# Using redactor with Active Admin

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic, redactor

[Redactor](http://redactorjs.com/) looks like an awesome rich text editor. I want to use redactor in a specific text area in my Active Admin CMS.

I found [this gem](https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails) which integrates redactor with rails, and so I tried to set it up:

**gemfile:**

```
gem 'redactor-rails'
```

**shell:**

```
$ bundle install
```

**config/redactor.yml**

```
lang: 'en'
autoresize: true
```

**config/initializer/active_admin.rb**

```
config.register_stylesheet 'redactor-rails.css'
config.register_javascript 'redactor-rails.js'
```

**the input in my active admin resource config**

```
f.input :contents, input_html: { id: "redactor_here", class: "redactor" }
```

I've checked:

- The redactor js/css files are being properly included (in the browser).
- The redactor class is being set on my textarea.

In the readme for redactor-rails [it says](https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails/#initialize-redactor) that after creating the textarea, you need to call the `redactor` helper to initialize redactor. However, that `redactor` helper isn't in the scope of an active admin form.. so where could I call it?

At the moment absolutely nothing is happening in the browser. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you add to your application.js: //= require redactor-rails

Comment: @Salil yep - I've now got it half working by [manually loading it with jQuery](https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails/issues/11), but there are some problems with the CSS

Comment: Alex, yup, I also have the same css problems. I faced the problem when I included the jquery plugin directly. So, it is the issue with the jquery and not the rails plugin.

Comment: We have it like this in our "app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js" file: 

//= require redactor
//= require redactor-rails/config

Comment: Upvote for pointing me towards a pretty sweet editor

Answer (score 3):

Hubble's directions didn't quite work for me, but here's what worked...
Follow the directions on the gem's page, then for Active Admin:

In active_admin.js, add

```
//= require redactor-rails
```

In active_admin.css.scss, add

```
@import "redactor-rails";
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of registering the stylesheet and js in active_admin.rb you should try

in **app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js**

```
//= require redactor
//= require redactor-rails/config
```

and in **app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss**

```
@import "redactor";
```

Answer (score 0):

In active_admin.js, add

```
//= require redactor-rails
```

In active_admin.css.scss, add this to top of the file

```
/*
  *= require redactor-rails
*/
```

This works for me :)
[refer this](https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails/issues/11#issuecomment-7830006)